# How to properly use COUNTIFS with a defined named range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have a formula that counts the number of contact attempts for each month. The problem I am facing is that the formula only goes up to row 2000. How can I rewrite my formula to adjust with newly added rows? Formula I am using

`=COUNTIFS(clientmenu!M8:HD2000,">="&$O$25,clientmenu!M8:HD2000,"<="&$O$26)`

[Link to my Workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqft18br7fznxfw/sampleWB.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Use dynamic data range instead of simple Cell references, will count newly added rows also. Or convert the Data Range into TABLE.

Comment: @fixer1234, his problem was different the entered Date were out of the Criteria, now I've filled `Dates in Col M & O in attached file`, beyond 2000 Rows and all Formula written by OP returns expected result. ☺

Comment: **Jose** ,, check the `Drop box` I've filled dates in more that 2000 rows and now all your Formulas are working !!

Comment: **Jose**,, check this link,,https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3s6f71uz8lgcmd/sampleWB.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: @RajeshS I used your suggestion for creating a dynamic range. I was able to google how to do it. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: did you check the file I've posted at Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to update the formula with cell references to rows past 2000.

```
=COUNTIFS(clientmenu!M8:HD9999,">="&$O$25,clientmenu!M8:HD9999,"<="&$O$26)
```